# Using swagger during AEM project build

Tags: swagger, aem

I'm new to swagger and AEM and currently, I'm doing a POC for my project where I have to use swagger to generate `.json/yaml` file for REST API during maven build (using AEM 6.5).
Can anyone please help me this or link to some documentation on this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What have you found?

Comment: i have searched through web many pages saw swagger maven example and tried to implement it without aem but that example is not generating any swagger.json file tried the refix also still no use.*
this is the plugin i am talking about? i am not sure whether we can use this in AEM or not as well still trying to do some experiment with this
 <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.4</version>

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I know about aem in combination with openapi is [swagger-aem](https://github.com/shinesolutions/swagger-aem). But probably this isn't what you are looking for.

This was released on the [adaptTo 2019](https://adapt.to/2019/en/schedule/swagger-aem---an-openapi-specification-for-aem.html)

Comment: Thank you Unkall, i will go through it and try to workout if any possibility.